# How to set up Jacoco code coverage tool in Eclipse for viewing colors in Java code?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-coverage, jacoco

I have setup jacoco in jenkins as part of functional test job to generate code coverage report. But I feel its very tough to understand.

Somewhere I read that covered and uncovered lines of code are shown in colors in Eclipse. This is for functional tests which connect to a stage where the whole business logic has been deployed. This is present inside Eclipse also as part of the project. How to set it up?

What difference the setup has for unit tests?

Comment: if i understand correctly do you want to get the code coverage report using eclipse?

Comment: No, using jacoco in eclipse. I want to see the color lines which indicate the piece of code is covered or not.

Comment: you can use EclEmma plugin in Eclipse which gives Jacoco code coverage report , but remember there is no way to exclude the class/package if you want it.

Comment: You means it will show colored coverage in local code even though I am using stage URL to connect to deployed version.
I tried this now, ran an FT with Coverage As-> TestNG, but its executing the test and returning below error
`An internal error occurred during: "Analyzing coverage session com.mycomp.rest.raj.MessageTest.operate (Feb 27, 2017 10:04:32 AM)".
(class: org/jacoco/core/internal/flow/ClassProbesAdapter, method: visitMethod signature: (ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor;) Wrong return type in function`

Comment: I didn't understand , did you mean you have test cases which are running on your local and your test cases  is hitting the  dev code which is deployed on some other machine ?

Comment: Yes. The project has different modules with FT, but the the FTs hit deployed code in stage.
`app ->
    module 1,
    module 2,
    module FT`

`app` is deployed in stage. and FTs have the endpoint URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136714/discussion-between-xploreraj-and-monis-majeed).

Answer (score 3):

You can download the **Eclemma** plugin from Eclipse marketplace.

1. Open Marketplace from Help menu.
2. Search for Eclemma Java Code Coverage.
3. Install and Restart Eclipse.
4. Right-Click on the project, select Coverage as -> JUnit Test

Answer (score 1):

http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/importexport.html mentions being able to import reports, but that they have to be exactly the same class files both when the report was generated and within the Eclipse workspace. It may work, it may not.